How to test Fragment with RiveAnimationView with help of robolectric
I added to the existing fragment RiveAnimationView and got an error message during test. Rive required initialization and has a native part inside the view so during the test
at the initialization point, the message appears:
com.getkeepsafe.relinker.MissingLibraryException: Could not find 'rive-android.dll'. Looked for: [armeabi-v7a], but only found: [java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 10
lib\([^\\]*)\rive-android.dll
          ^].
androidx.startup.StartupException: com.getkeepsafe.relinker.MissingLibraryException: Could not find 'rive-android.dll'. Looked for: [armeabi-v7a], but only found: [java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 10
lib\([^\\]*)\rive-android.dll
          ^].
    at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize(AppInitializer.java:187)
    at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize(AppInitializer.java:138)
    at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.initializeComponent(AppInitializer.java:117)

looks like this requires some native libs but I haven't found some info regarding that.
Is there is a way to test it or there is a built strategy to test native like views with help of Robolectric (v4.12)
